# Selenium Webdriver get custom attribute value

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

How can i get value of custom attribute ('173136' from data-id and 'NORMAL' from data-status for example) inside of div using Selenium Webdriver in ruby?

`<div class="trow " data-id="173136" data-status="NORMAL" data-running="false">`

I found that watir-webdriver can afford that https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/get-attribute-values-of-the-html-element/, but as I mentioned we are using selemium-webdriver. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy, just:

```
browser.div(somes identificator like :xpath or :text).data_id
browser.div(somes identificator like :xpath or :text).data_status
```

But, yes, it's for Watir..for selenium it's somes like:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "some xpath").attribute("data-id")
driver.find_element(:xpath, "some xpath").attribute("data-status")
```

Comment: I think there is a typo. The string passed to the `attribute` method should exactly match the attribute name. For example, it should be `data-id` instead of `data_id`.